# Style not complied in rails when modifying imported files for sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I have my styles organized in rails project as follows.

|-stylesheets
|--styles
|----file1.scss
|----file2.scss
|-application.css.scss
|-main.scss

In my **application.css.scss** file, i configured to pull only *main.scss* file so i can use the sass mixins and variables globally across other scss files inside styles folder

*= require_self
 *= require main

I have used main.scss file to use the @import rule to import the scss files from the styles folder like

**@import "styles/file1.scss"**
**@import "styles/file2.scss"**
**@import "styles/file3.scss"**
etc...

So the **main.scss** file only contains imports

This has helped me to use the scss mixins and variables across the scss file.

The Problem is whenever i make changes to the files inside the styles folder or any other files that are imported in main the assets are not rebuild. The asset pipeline is only looking for the changes done in main.scss file and not the files that are imported. So i have to make changes in main.scss like add or remove a space and save to rebuild/recompile the scss files.

Can anyone tell me the workaround for this. I want to able to recompile/rebuild the assets when any of the included scss file changes.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I am new to rails

Answer (score 0):

Try installing https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload

Try installing https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload

Comment: unfortunately that is not what i am seeking. i want my main.scss file to compile when the included files are modified. so the correct css is generated with the changes done in included files.